# Track user impressions of view items in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I have a `ListView` with a set of children vertically listed (View objects) to be viewed by the users. I have to track the the user views, say, 
a. If a user views a set of items for around 1 second, I should track the impressions. 
b. If the same user scrolls the items out of the viewport and return back, I should track again, if he viewed for 1 second.

I tried several options like `getGlobalVisibleRect()`, `getLocalVisibleRect()`, `getLocationOnScreen()` and they are confusing in the first place and didn't help me get the right coordinates and visibility of the child items of the `listView`.

I checked [Track impression of items in an android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808069/track-impression-of-items-in-an-android-listview) which is a bit similar to my requirement but I thought to check if there is a better solution. I am new to Android and apologies if I am not clear on some explanations

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired result, I think we have two different solutions. First, create Handler for each of the item and call / remove in scroll view if it is visible. But this is very much stupid one as creating so many Handlers will make your app's life hell.

Second and best way is to use call / remove a single Handler for the entire visible items. If it persist for a time "A second" (1 second for you), use impression count in each of your item's model class and increase it with ++ operator.

You can add scroll listener in your listivew. The script will be like-

```
 ListView listView = null;
int firstVisibleItemIndex = 0;
int visibleCount = 0;

Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = firstVisibleItemIndex; i < firstVisibleItemIndex + visibleCount; i++) {
            try {
                //Get impression count from model for the visible item index i
                int count = modelList.get(i).getImpressionCount();
                //Set impression count to the model for the visible item index i
                modelList.get(i).setImpressionCount(++count);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

//Can call this method body in onCreate directly
private void addListScrollListener() {
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // You cat determine first and last visible items here
            // final int lastVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount - 1;

            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            firstVisibleItemIndex = firstVisibleItem;
            visibleCount = visibleItemCount;
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

I assume that you will bind your ListView with the id in your onCreate method. Also you can call the listener thing in your onCreate after binding the view with the variable.

I hope this will work for your requirement.

Let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thanks Hari for the reply. Yes, I am binding the ListView and added onScrollListener to it. In the solution, what if the user remains in the same screen for more than 1 second like 2 or 4 seconds scrolling very slowly. The same set of indices would be sent to the callback. This will create duplicate impressions even if the items are in the same viewport. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Yes @KarthikeyanAlagarswamy, I have mentioned the Handler in my above code and runnable. once user scrolls in speed then last handler will be removed to call and will reset once it is in ideal state. You can adjust the time as per you, for me I have kept this 1000 ms. Go through my code thoroughly and you will see your solution. Also check the commented lines. I open the comment which will be needed for your code. Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the code snippet inside onScrollListener and tried the solution. I see that, after scrolling slowly, the callback method is called and I am able to see the right indices inside callback. So, to avoid duplication, I will have to compare the current and previous set of indices and track unique impressions , correct?

Comment: yes you can keep a comparison here that if in present and previous total number of indices, there are common indices (intersection value), you can avoid the duplicate impressions.

Comment: Thanks Hari. The problem that I see is, the callback is called only when the scrolling stops and not after 1 second (during scrolling).

Comment: Yes this should be. The handler will be called after the scroll is stopped but as there is postdelayed so the runnable will be called after the time interval (1 second). You can share your updated code if having issue.